# sorting structure

Tags: c

I want to sort the name of my rectangular with respect to the value of its areas which I computed and saved it to my structure. but I faced a number of errors about my strcpy. would you please tell me what is the problem with my logic?

```
    typedef struct coordinate{
    float x[MAX_REC];
    float y[MAX_REC];
    char name[MAX_REC][IDENTIFIER+1];
    }coor;

    typedef struct perimeter_area{
    float perimeter[MAX_REC];
    float area[MAX_REC];
    char  name_s[IDENTIFIER];
    }pa;


    int main(){

.
.
.
insertion_sort(&f2,number_new_row);
.
.
.
}
void insertion_sort(pa *f2,int row){
    float tmp_area;
    float tmp_perimeter;
    char  tmp_name[IDENTIFIER];
    int j;

    for(int i=0; i<row; ++i){
        tmp_area=f2->area[i];
        strcpy(tmp_name,f2->name_s[i]);
        j=i-1;
        while(j>=0 && tmp_area<f2->area[j+1]){
            f2->area[j+1]=f2->area[j];
            j--;
        }
        f2->area[j+1]=tmp_area;
        strcpy(f2->name_s[i],f2->name_s[j]);
        strcpy(f2->name_s[j],tmp_name);
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. my second structure in the part name_s has to be a 2D array.